# Android App Links - Pattern with # in URL

Tags: android, applinks

I am trying to implement Android App Links. The website where the url is linked to, is developped with Angular, thus all URLs have a #  in it (#! exactly).

> http://myDomain/#!/vehicle/schema_id

I cannot find the good pattern that works with the #

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="www.mydomain.com"
            android:pathPattern="/#!/vehicle/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

this pathPattern works perfectly with an url without the # such as

> http://myDomain/!/vehicle/schema_id for instance

So my issue is specific to the dash :-S

If have tried :

- /\#!/vehicle/.*
- /\\#!/vehicle/.*
- /.+/vehicle/.*
- /../vehicle/.*
- /*/vehicle/.*
- /%23!/vehicle/.*

and other that I don't recall

Thanks in advance for your possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot use # symbol in URL for deep links because Android thinks that every symbol after # is [Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

In other words system detects URL only as http://myDomain/ it doesnt see part after #.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am doomed then :(

Comment: @TweetyB change url on server if you can or dont use pathPattern at all, open app and then check url.

Comment: thanks will do that, open the main activity on domain call then redirect to activity expected. As so I will have proper navigation stack as weel